# NVIDIA SLI Bridge recommendation

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I have an ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming motherboard
I have 2 NVIDIA GeForce 1070 GTX GPUs
I want a bridge for these two.I am looking for ASUS ROG SLI HB Bridge and they have two models 3 slot and 4 slot, which one is the right product for my motherboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]The 3 slot model is the one you need.
With your hardware combination you will have one empty slot in between the two cards. The 4 slot model is only needed if you have two empty slots in between the cards.